# how to make a custom easing function that eases between given breakpoints

Tags: javascript, html

I need a custom easing function that takes breakpoints as parameters and eases between those breakpoints similar to this but this doesn't work:

```
function makeEasing(breakpoints) {
  return t => {
    const iPoint = Math.floor(t / breakpoints.length),
          iDest = iPoint + 1;
    return (breakpoints[iPoint] - breakpoints[iDest]) * (t);

  };
}
```

Usage:

```
const easing = makeEasing([0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5]);

easing(0) // 0.5
// easing(0 + 1/4 * 0.5) // 0.25
easing(1/4) // 0.0
easing(2/4) // 0.5
easing(3/4) // 1.0
// easing(3/4 + 1/4 * 0.5) // 0.75
easing(4/4) // 0.5
```

<strike>let's say we can use this elastic easing function</strike>

```
const easing = t => {
  return .04 * t / (--t) * Math.sin(25 * t);
};
```

i have two variables in the range [0.0, 1.0]

`impact` and `targetImpact`

I want `impact` to reach `targetImpact` slowly so I do:

```
// delta is passed time
impact += (targetImpact - impact) * delta * 0.001;
```

This works for interpolating between `impact` and `targetImpact`.

But I want elastic effect when `impact` reaches `targetImpact`, that is

`impact` goes up to `targetImpact + 0.2`, 
then goes down to `targetImpact - 0.2`,
then goes up to `targetImpact + 0.1`,
then goes down to `targetImpact - 0.1`,
finally reaches `targetImpact`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest way for you to have this effect is to create 4 impacts in a row with your different `targetImpact`. Use the previous `targetImpact` as `impact` for next one.

Edit:

```
var easing = 0;

function makeEasing(breakpoints) {
    breakpoints.forEach(t => {
        let iPoint = Math.floor(t / breakpoints.length),
            iDest = iPoint + 1;
        easing = (breakpoints[iPoint] - breakpoints[iDest]) * (t);
    })
}

makeEasing([0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5]);
```

Comment: I could but i dont know how you run your code precisely, can you add it ? 
If not, use an array with your "breakpoints" [`0.2`, `0.2`, `0.1`,  `0.1`] and loop on it with your `impact` value being updated each time the loop run. Run it with `arrayOfBreakpoints.forEach(yourFunction)`

Comment: That cannot work if you use this as is for sure
I don't know what is the final usage of this code, but you can calculate each value with the edited answer.
Yeah, what is `t` in your code ?
Also, why use `const` everywhere ?

Comment: I'm glad you resolved your problem with my pseudo code solution !! Can you mark this question as resolved / upvote my answer please :)

Comment: well your pseudo code contains problems, i give you credit for giving me the idea of breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @AppyGG for giving the idea this now works:

```js
function makeEasing(breakpoints) {
  const spaces = breakpoints.length - 1;
  return t => {
    const iPoint = Math.floor(t / (1 / spaces)),
          iDest = iPoint + 1;
    return breakpoints[iPoint] + (breakpoints[iDest] - breakpoints[iPoint]) * smoothstep(0, 1/spaces, (t % (1/spaces)));

  };
}


function smoothstep (min, max, value) {
  var x = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (value-min)/(max-min)));
  return x*x*(3 - 2*x);
};


function round(v, d = 100) {
  return Math.round(v * d) / d;
}

function testEasing(easing) {
  for (let i = 0; i< 1; i+= 0.01) {
    console.log(round(i), round(easing(i)));
  }
}

const easing2 = makeEasing([0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5]);

testEasing(easing2);
```